# how to compare list with string

Tags: android

im comparing database values with packageinfo   this is screenshot  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wf6iJ.jpg

i get all database values in list List arraylist = db.getAllApps();

how do i compare this list with list of install ap package name? below is my code snap plz help me how do i compare??? this line not filter values
            if ( (p.packageName).equals(arraylist))  how do i filter values so match and display only that value in list that match with database

```
                   private List<App> loadInstalledApps(boolean includeSysApps) {
    List<App> apps = new ArrayList<App>();

    // the package manager contains the information about all installed apps
    PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();

    List<PackageInfo> packs = packageManager.getInstalledPackages(0); 
List arraylist = db.getAllApps();

    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
        PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);
        ApplicationInfo applicationInfo = p.applicationInfo;




//  if (arraylist.equals(p.packageName))

        if ( (p.packageName).equals(arraylist))


        {
            App app = new App();
            app.setTitle(p.applicationInfo.loadLabel(packageManager)
                    .toString());
            app.setPackageName(p.packageName);
            app.setVersionName(p.versionName);
            app.setVersionCode(p.versionCode);
            CharSequence description = p.applicationInfo
                    .loadDescription(packageManager);
            app.setDescription(description != null ? 
        description.toString()
                    : "");
            apps.add(app);
            // }
        }
    }
    return apps;
    }
```

Comment: I didn't get it. Do you want a function which compares two List<String>? Use search form above in that case.

Comment: Please stop asking the same question over and over.

Comment: i just only wants to display only that application in list view that package name exist in database so how do i compare them??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to find in list

```
if(arraylist.contains(p.packageName)) {
      //your code here
}
```

This code works if arrayList is a list of string, if is other class, you have two options

1) Compare all object

```
if(arraylist.contains(p)) {
      //your code here
}
```

2) Compare by packageName(or other attribute)

```
bool isInList = false;
for (MyClass object : array list) {
    if (object.packageName.equals(p.packageName)) {
        isInList = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (isInList) {
    //your code here
}
```

Comment: Contains check for references, while checking package existence needs to use .equals() Your answer is wrong.

Comment: ok i'll check ur solution

Comment: wow is help me ur gr8 i post so much no one help me only u  carefully understand my problem thnk u sooo much

Answer (score 1):

If you want to see if the `packageName` is IN the list of `packageInfo`, then it would be easiest to have another loop where you compare the `packageName` to the `packageName` of each `packageInfo` in your arraylist

I am assuming that your `.equals()` method works because I have no idea what a PackageInfo object is

```
for (PackageInfo pi : arrayList) {
    if (pi.equals(p) {
        //your code here
    }
}
```

Comment: @HayyaAnam p is a variable I found in your code `PackageInfo p = packs.get(i);`